# modular and flexible programming

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn how to make a modular program. So what I want to do is read an array of integers.
Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NMAX 10


void read (int *n, int a[NMAX]);

int main()
{
    int n, a[NMAX];
    read(&n,a);
    return 0;

}
```

Then I saved this file 'read.cpp':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NMAX 10

void read (int *n, int a[NMAX])
{
    int i;
    printf("dati n:\n");
    scanf("%d",n);
    for (i=1;i<=*n;i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]= ",i);
        scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);
    }

}
```

read.cpp compiles succesfully, but when I compile the main function I get the error "no reference to read".

Comment: `.cpp` extension is for C++, not C.

Comment: [OT]:Btw, index `i` should go from `[0; n-1]` instead of `[1; n]`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C++. If this was C++ you'd probably return some stdlib container instead of writing to some memory allocated elsewhere with no way to check e.g. size constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Include `read.cpp` when compiling.

```
g++ -o out main.cpp read.cpp
```

or

add `#include "read.cpp"` in main program

Comment: i added the include, and I get a TON of errors I don`t understand. In file included from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1:0,
                 from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1,
                 from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1,
                 from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1,
                 from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1,
                 from E:\codeblocks\modul2\read.cpp:1, and so on

Comment: which compiler and OS you are using?

Comment: i am sorry sujin, your commentary was very good and it works, I just made a mistake that I didn`t notice in that include. Thank you!

Comment: The right way to do is to have both files in the project. The `#include` cpp file solution is evil.

Comment: What do you mean? I have both the main function and the read function in the same project.

Comment: @user3078259 your codeblock might have the option to `add file to project` . add your `read.cpp` file using that option then compile. i am not sure about this because i not used codeblocks. This is what @Jaroad42 said.

Comment: what does "undefined reference to WinMain@16" mean?